# Remove Scroll from webpage on mobile view

Tags: javascript, css, html, wordpress

Url : http://projects.wbcomdesigns.com/vtc/all-courses/

This page is working fine in desktop view and also after doing inspect element in chrome and mozila no scroll in site but in mobile device it has a big scroll in page and i am stuck here from 3 days.please provide me solution as soon as possible.

Comment: What element has a scroll bar? It looks like the fixed header causes the page to jank, but I wasn't seeing a scroll bar that looked problematic.

Comment: Actually the above site work perfectly on the chrome and mozilla device Simulator but when we test the above URL on the mobile device then it generate scroll horizontally. I want solution to resolve the scroll from the devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an element that is breaking the layout of the page because it has an inline style setting it's width to be `1349px`. The problematic element has the class of `vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_custom_1474973756972 vc_row-has-fill vc_column-gap-15 vc_row-no-padding vc_row-o-content-top vc_row-flex`. Remove the `width: 1349px` and your site should look correct again (while that specific element may need some reformatting).

---

<sup>*Sidenote*: the site is running very slowly for me - load times around 7s. Do you have all of the caching enabled?</sup>

Comment: yes you are right.thanks.its working fine now

Comment: Removing the inline width of 1349px removes scroll in the inner pages...but home page still have scroll in mobile view ...if possible please provide solution

Comment: Could you provide a link to the page in question?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use fixed width to any div inline or in less make it in percentage value or VW and in desktop view use max-width for container and width as 100%;